# What does Gern mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> A: Ja, ja, genau . Danke, Frau Weyer.
>   Ach , und bitte auch noch die Adresse von Herrn Theissen aus Detmold.
>
> B: **Gern**. - Hier: Frank Theissen.

Is ***Gern*** the short version of ***Gern geschehen***?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. *Gern geschehen* is a response to someone thanking you for something that you have done. In your example, when B says *gern*, she has not yet done anything with respect to the request (and, consequently, A hasn't yet thanked her for it), so *gern geschehen* would not fit.

Rather, *gern* means *with pleasure*. B indicates to A that she is happy to look up the address.

> A: Ach , und bitte auch noch die Adresse von Herrn Theissen aus
>   Detmold.
>
> B: **Gern.** *(With pleasure.)* - Hier: Frank Theissen, Bahnhofplatz 1, 32123 Detmold.
>
> A: Vielen Dank!
>
> B: **Gern geschehen.** *(You're welcome.)*

Answer (score 5):

No, it's a »shorty« for

> Das mache ich gern
>   *(certainly)*

*»Gern geschehen«* refers to the past.

Comment: In other words: *You are welcome*.

Answer (score 1):

In

> A: Ja, ja, genau . Danke, Frau Weyer.
>   Ach , und bitte auch noch die Adresse von Herrn Theissen aus Detmold.
>
> B: Gern. - Hier: Frank Theissen.

[*Gern* means:](https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=gern)

> **gern**  adverb
>   gladly *adv*
>   Ich würde gerne alles tun, um dir zu helfen. –– I would gladly do anything to help you.
>
> and seldom
>   with pleasure *adv*  ·  willingly *adv*  ·  readily *adv*  ·  fondly *adv*  ·  fain *adv*  ·  lief *adv* [oldfashioned]

But since it is so overused, the above translation should not be taken literally. Most people just express a filler like "Here you go", "of course", "naturally" with only an ever so slightly tiny little bit of elevated politeness attached to *gern*.